# TextBased application on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, foxpro

I'm developing a Windows Forms application in .NET, this app is going to replace a current DOS FOXPRO application; however, I need to keep this application, at least for a couple of months. I think to add a quick access where the user can open an MDI form with the DOS apps. I couldn't find a control which enable to open the text base application on a C# FORM (the application is similar to the old [Norton Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNorton_Commander_5.51.png))

Does anyone know if it is possible? If it is, how can I do that?

Regards.
Gustavo.

Comment: Does the DOS app have to be run from within the MDI form, as in shown inside the MDI window?  Can the DOS application just be launched from with the .NET application and run in it's own window?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do it: [Embedding a Console in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application)

For both WinForms and WPF. What's not clear is the situation with 16-bit applications, of which FoxPro for DOS is one. Because they won't run on 64-bit Windows in any way, shape or form. This restriction may or may not apply to your situation.